# How can I use a physical button to print something to my thermal printer?

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi2, thermal-printer

I recently purchased an AdaFruit thermal printer. (https://learn.adafruit.com/pi-thermal-printer/overview)

I just started programming for a class I am in and using a raspberry pi. I loved how straightforward the directions were on AdaFruit but can't seem to find any instructions on what I am looking for. If I wanted to print something to my thermal printer with the "touch of a button" (and I mean a literal button you press with your finger) how would I go about that? I don't even know what to put into a search engine. I am assuming I would use python but not quite sure where to start. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Most thermal printers work by sending a a stream of bytes to the printer.

Search ESC/POS and you will find good examples.

A quick search found this: https://python-escpos.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/raspi.html